# Hibernate não consegue achar uma coluna existente, ERRORCODE=-4460

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Estou tendo uma dificuldade no meu sistema onde o SQL com o hibernate não consegue achar uma coluna específica pelo Java, a mesma query retorna o resultado certo quando rodada pelo SQL. IDE utilizada é o NetBeans.

A query é a seguinte:

```
SELECT DE_CONTEUDO FROM ASP.PDI_EMAIL_MODELO WHERE CD_EMAIL_MODELO = 1;
```

Quando rodada pelo SQL:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando rodada pelo Java e Hibernate o programa emite o seguinte erro:

```
Parâmetro inválido: nome de coluna desconhecido CD_EMAIL_MODELO. ERRORCODE=-4460, SQLSTATE=null
```

O método Java é esse:

```
public List pesquisar(){
    String sql = "SELECT DE_CONTEUDO FROM ASP.PDI_EMAIL_MODELO WHERE CD_EMAIL_MODELO = 1";
    Session session = HibernateUtil.open();
    List query = session.createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity(EmailModelo.class).list();
    session.close();    
    return query;
}
```

A Entidade é a seguinte:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ASP.PDI_EMAIL_MODELO")
public class EmailModelo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CD_EMAIL_MODELO")
    private long cdEmailModelo;

    @Column(name = "DE_CONTEUDO")
    private String conteudo;

    // Getters e setters simples ...
}
```

E o hibernate.cfg está mapeado desse jeito:

```
<mapping class="persistencia.EmailModelo"/>
```

Detalhes adicionais:

- Pesquisas com linhas não existentes na tabela retornam uma lista vazia sem erro no programa. Ex: CD_EMAIL_MODELO = 20
- Já tive problemas com querys nessa IDE que a solução foi literalmente escrever a mesma query em caixa baixa porém tentei isso nesse caso e não resolveu

Comment: Qual banco de dados está usando? Qual driver está usando para conexão com o banco de dados?

Comment: O banco de dados é o DB2 da IBM e o driver é o 'IBM DB2 Universal Driver'

Comment: Qual a versão do Hibernate? Qual versão do driver está usando? Existem problemas na leitura dos nomes da colunas relacionados a versão do Hibernate e do driver de conexão para Db2 em uma combinação de versões antigas de ambos

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas combinações de versão do Hibernate com a versão do driver de conexão do DB2 [que podem gerar este erro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981711/db2jcc4-jar-invalid-parameter-unknown-column-name).

A explicação é que versões mais antigas do Hibernate (3.x) lêem o nome da coluna dos metadados da tabela usando o campo `columnName`, sendo que a especificação JDBC requer que seja usado o campo `columnLabel`.

Versões antiga do JDBC não eram claros quanto esta distinção, então era normal que a implementação dos drivers ocorresse de forma diferente entre os bancos de dados. A IBM mudou este comportamento na versão 9.5 do driver.

A solução, pelo que parece, são duas: atualizar o Hibernate para uma versão 4.x ou atualizar o driver de conexão. Se por motivos de compatibilidade a atualização do driver não for possível, o [parâmetro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884794/db2-query-unknown-column-name-errorcode-4460-sqlstate-null) `useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics=2` pode ser usado com o driver de conexão mais novo para resolver este problema e manter a compatibilidade.

Comment: Minha versão do Hibernate é a 4.3.11 porém eu acho que o problema é esse mesmo já que quando quando pesquiso uma query que retorna a linha inteira (SELECT * FROM) ele retorna sem problemas e quando peço uma coluna em específico (SELECT DE_CONTEUDO FROM) ele da esse erro. Obrigado pela ajuda.